# Writing long number to excel from pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to figure out how to change the format of one of my columns when writing to a excel file. Currently if a number is over 15 digits the end digits get truncated. Setting column format to a string negates this issue. I cant figure out how to do this before I write to to a file though

Comment: 15 digits appears to be an [excel maximum](http://superuser.com/questions/437764/why-is-excel-truncating-my-16-digit-numbers).

Comment: @nbryans - What's weird, is you can *show* greater than 15 digits, even if you can't actually have 15 digits. (I can get Excel to show 100+ digits via Formatting, but you can't get that precise).

Comment: It is the maximum when dealing with numbers. I just want my number output for a column to be formatted as a string.

Comment: I think string is better than any number type if the length is very long.

Comment: Some ideas for you: http://superuser.com/questions/234997/how-can-i-stop-excel-from-eating-my-delicious-csv-files-and-excreting-useless-da

Comment: I don't know pandas very well, but I would think you can convert the data (in your dataframe) to **actually be strings**. Maybe this is in-place, or maybe you have to make a new dataframe with the stringified data. You could use Python's `str()` function, or maybe pandas (or NumPy) has something more efficient for converting a whole column. But anyway, once the data type really is just string, then it should be written to the Excel file as string naturally.

Comment: If you really want to have better control over formatting, then it's better to use the Excel-writing packages directly (OpenPyXL or XlsxWriter). Personally, I recommend XlsxWriter.